# Putnam Problem A-1 2008 3 variable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

I looked at a Putnam problem from 2008, here it is: [Putnam Link](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2008.pdf)

" Let $f : R^2 → R$ be a function such that $f(x, y)+ f(y,z)+
f(z, x) = 0$ for all real numbers $x, y, z$. Prove that
there exists a function $g : R → R$ such that $f(x, y) =
g(x)−g(y)$ for all real numbers $x, y$."

Here is [Their Solution.](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2008s.pdf)

**My solution:**

Since $f(x,y) + f(y,z) + f(z, x) = 0$ we know that:

$z + x + y = 0$ hence $z = x - y$

Which means: $f(x,y)= x - y$

The only function that fits it $g(t) = t$

We have "proved," that there is a function because we found a function.

Would this be correct?

Comment: How do you conclude from $f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x)=0$ that $x+y+z=0$?

Comment: You are asserting that for every $x,y,z$, we have $x+y+z=0$?  Did you try testing this on a few triples, like maybe $x=y=z=1$?

Comment: I knew it couldnt be that easy.........

Answer (score 3):

the easiest consequence of the functional equation is that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
f(x,x)=0
$$
so $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x,y)=-f(y,x)
$$
and from
$$
f(x,0) + f(0,y)+ f(y,x) =0
$$
we deduce:
$$
f(x,y) = f(x,0)+f(0,y) \\
= f(x,0)-f(y,0)
$$
which has the required form, setting $g(x)=f(x,0)$

Comment: How is $f(x, 0) + f(0, y) + f(y,x) = 0$ ??

Comment: use the triple $x,0,y$ in the functional equation

Comment: Oh right, it holds for **any** $x,y,z$ correct/